# Default value for length column is null when tracking lines QField

Tags: qfield

I have designed a project to capture lines with QField. I have a length column with a default value that is calculated with the $length function; When I draw the line manually it works perfectly but when I use the live tracking of the line in QField it does not calculate it and only the null value comes out. How could I automatically calculate the length at the end of the tracking? This is the config for field length:

[image]

Comment: Live tracking with Qfield